# How to construct require param method of Rails API controller for a multipart request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-api

I'm stuck on a problem since 2 days on Ruby on Rails (I learn it in self-taught for 3 months ) and I don't find a 'rails convention' way to resolve it. 
I'm building a classic API where a user can create a dream destination which have a name, a description and an image.

I have a `dream_destination` model :

```rb
class Api::V1::DreamDestination < ApplicationRecord
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

  has_one_attached :image

  belongs_to :user

  validates :image, presence: true

  def get_image_url
    url_for(self.image)
  end
end
```

Here my migration file to better describe the attached table :

```rb
class CreateApiV1DreamDestinations < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :api_v1_dream_destinations do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.text :description
      t.boolean :visited, default: false

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I've my create route in my controller:

```rb
# POST /api/v1/dream_destinations
  def create
    @api_v1_dream_destination = current_user.dream_destinations.new(dream_destination_params)

    if @api_v1_dream_destination.save
      render json: @api_v1_dream_destination, status: :created, location: @api_v1_dream_destination
    else
      render json: @api_v1_dream_destination.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

---

**The problem is :** 
My request to this create route must be a multipart content type one because it mix a Json object and a file (an image file in my case). But I don't find how to allow that with the define param method of my controller which is based on JSON content type :

```rb
def dream_destination_params
      params.require(:dream_destination).permit(:name, :description)
    end
```

Here is an exemple of the response when my request is construct like this (I'm using PAW for testing my endpoints):

[Screenshot of my request on PAW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q5Lj7.png)

```json
{"error":"undefined method `permit' for \"{\\\"name\\\":\\\"Example city\\\",\\\"description\\\":\\\"It doesn't work and it hurts me\\\"}\":String\n\n params.require(:dream_destination).permit(:name, :description)\n ^^^^^^^"}
```

Some help for a rails noobie ? 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

With your request, `params.require(:dream_destination)` only return a string, cause `undefined method 'permit' for ... String` error. I think you can fix with 3 methods.

1. Simply change your request data keys as Rails want.
   [image: post man request]
   And in the controller:

```
def dream_destination_params
  params.require(:dream_destination).permit(:name, :description, :image)
end
```

2. Manually process your data.
   In the controller:

```
def dream_destination_params
  data = JSON.parse params.require(:dream_destination)
  data['image'] = params[:image]
  data
end
```

3. The hard way

- Add `Content-Type=application/json` to your request headers.
- Transform request data into raw data `{"dream_destination": { "name", "description":"...", "image": "image_data"}}` with `image_data` is inline encoded image data( as base64 ).
- Change your controller to handle data.

```
def dream_destination_params
  params.require(:dream_destination)
end
# In case rails can't handle inline encoded data, you might have to do it yourself.
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot @hoangdd ! A complete answer which solved my problem !
I chose the first solution because nothing to modify in my code, I suspected that I was constructing my query the wrong way but I couldn't find the error.. Thank you again!